# Bedeutung von "bei der man immer den anderen mitdenkt"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Ein verschleierter Blick auf Humphrey Bogart, dazu diese rauchige Stimme, mit der sie ihn um Feuer bittet: Lauren Bacall war 19, als sie 1944 "Haben und Nichthaben" drehte. ...  Die Bacall, die bürgerlich Betty Joan Perske hieß, war eine große Schauspielerin, **bei der man immer den anderen, der Feuer gibt, mitdenkt**.

Was bedeutet der fette Teil des Abschnitts? Ich habe das Wort "mitdenken" [im Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/mitdenken) nachgeschlagen, aber die Benutzung von "bei der" und dem Dativ "den anderen" finde ich immer noch verwirrend.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a native German speaker and still don't know what the author wanted to tell me with that sentence.

Comment: Ein *sich* hätte wohl nicht geschadet.

Comment: @Harald: "bei der man immer auch an Bogart denkt" ist gemeint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es bedeutet, dass man unweigerlich immer an jemanden erinnert wird, an jemanden denken muss. Hier also Lauren Bacall, bei der man sich immer "den anderen" (konkret Humphrey Bogart) dazu denkt.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer focuses on the `jemanden mitdenken` aspect, which I only know as "für jemanden mitdenken" (to do the thinking for someone else), I'd like to provide an answer to `bei der` und `den anderen`.

### "bei der"

literally meaning something as `with her` or `regarding her` used to say all possibilities of the following. When I see her; When I think of her; When she is around, When she apprears on stage, When one speaks about her... Just every time it is about her. For a male person one would say `bei dem`.

### "man immer"

Especially in the combination with `bei der`, it means that one does something whenever it is about her.

### "den anderen, der Feuer gibt"

This just describes the object as `the one that lighted the cigarette` On could also have said. `muss man immer Humphrey mitdenken`.